# Coin Combinatorics: Minimum amount of coins for given value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I was just doing a bit of thinking on coin combinatorics today when I began thinking of this question: You have a set of coins, greater than £2, but you cannot pay someone £2 without needing change. What is the largest possible value of this set of coins?

P.s.: This is not homework, just curiosity! (I've been thinking about it all day. It's been really bugging me.)

Comment: Could you explain a little more? You could have any number of £1 coins and still be unable to pay someone 50p.

Comment: sorry. I meant that you cannot pay someone £2 without needing change. Editing it now

Comment: Maybe 3x50p,9x20p,1x5p,2x2p=339p?

Comment: Interesting, but how do you prove your answer?

Comment: I don't I leave it to you to prove or find a better solution! :)

Comment: You're answer doesn't work though. I could get £2 exactly by, 2x50p + 5x20p

Comment: "greater than £2" ??

Comment: As this is an international site, you should indicate in your question information that people from elsewhere will need to know to help you answer it: namely, what denominations are available.

Comment: @GCab, I'm pretty sure that means **summing to** greater than £2. That could be worded more clearly.

Comment: @msh210 it would be desirable, together with current denominations, in fact

Comment: So despite the misleading title, the question is the following. Coins have denominations: 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1. Find the largest possible value for a set of coins that does not allow you to pay 200 exactly. One idea would be: 9x20, 1x50, 1x5, 2x2 = 239.